# Foreign Key between Django application

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

In Django, I would like to link foreign key from another app. Bellow is the method for same application, but in my case, they are two different applications on same project.

App Client Model :

`name = models.CharField(max_length=64)`

App Invoice Model :

`client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

First you need to import model into application.

```
from some_other_app.models import client

class Invoice(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userpostchallenge")
```

You are putting quotes around the model name don't do that.

I misunderstood, now i realized what you want to that so here is updated answer.

Comment: I understand that i cannot do it, only same app models can be linked with foreign key, but not on different apps either if it s same project. The idea is that i have project with 3 applications, client, supplier, both have to be linked to product app. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it can be 3 different application but no foreign key relationship. You import models into any application and do what you want that's it.

Comment: pls example : 2 apps, client (models : name, phone) and invoice (date, client_name). how i can link them so i can get client names as we do on foreignkey method if same app. thanks a lot bro

Comment: If it works fine accept the answer because other can see it has accepted answer. now it's up-to you. thanks